# Storing a font on WebLogic Server for use in a PDF

Tags: fonts, weblogic

I'm using the [flying-saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) library to generate a PDF in a servlet that then returns the PDF through the response output stream to a JSP.

I need some of the content inside of the PDF to have a certain font ("MICR Encoding" in particular).  I have tested this font locally in a test web page and successfully displayed content with the font applied.

However, the PDF that's getting generated isn't recognizing the font.  I *suspect* that I need to place the font file in a place where WebLogic Server will be able to access it so that when the PDF is being created in the servlet, WebLogic Server will have access to the font to embed it into the PDF.

Do any of you have any idea where font files need to be placed/implemented in WebLogic Server such that they will be recognized when content is built on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...just had to use `@font-face` and then was able to reference the font file that I uploaded onto the server.

My CSS file looks like this (I'm running WLS locally)...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MICR Encoding";
    src: url("https://127.0.0.1:4443/fonts/micrenc.ttf");
}
.bank_numbers {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.1in;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "MICR Encoding", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.2in;
}
```